# HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet%2Cstatus&alt=json returned "Internal error encountered."

Tags: google-apis-explorer

Getting 500 error when making a https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists request.
I'm using the python implementation provided here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert.
The same request worked yesterday, so I tend to believe this is not on my side.
Is there anything I might be missing?

Comment: An internal error on someone else's site means they've got a problem on their end. It's internal (thus the *internal error*), which means they need to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The message error usually is more descriptive than the one you put. I had the same problem than you (same message and just yesterday) and tryed a direct call to YouTube API via this page: (you will see a try it pane in the right where you can easily put the call parameters): https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert

After executing it, I cuolud find the complete error message that was:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "youtube.api.v3.PlaylistInsertResponse.Error",
        "reason": "RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

Probably calling the API in that way will give you the full detailed reason of the error.

Comment: Thanks. Finally it was a problem with quota (it was exceeded). Thanks a lot.